# Is it possible to create a Wither Boss Farm in Vanilla Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to create a Wither Boss Farm? I am in need of many Nether Stars. I have stockpiled a stack of Wither Skulls so I can create them, I just don't want to have to do all the work. I would rather sit back AFK while it goes through the lot.

Is there a way to automate the placing and killing of Withers of this scale? hopefully with a hopper collection solution to collect the Stars so they don't de-spawn. I know how to kill one, but it takes manual input to reset and start the killing process, and I want this to be automated.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible with a complicated redstone setup. I'll get back to you after some experimentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wither skulls can be automatically placed using a dispenser:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no way to automatically place or generate soulsand. The best you can do is have a stockpile pushed in with pistons.

[image]

You'll then need another dispenser to drop water onto the wither so that the explosions do not damage anything, and finally some sort of killing device. The best way to do this is have pistons push the wither up into the roof of the nether, suffocating it.

Also remember to have some hoppers or hopper minecarts below to pick up the star.

Hook it all up with a timer so that:

1. Soulsand is pushed in
2. Dispensers place wither skulls
3. Dispenser places water
4. Wither explodes
5. Wither is killed
6. Water is picked back up
7. Repeat

Comment: Note that suffocating the wither will take quite a long time because it regenerates half a heart every second.

Comment: You could hook up a dispenser to fire arrows at the wither too

Comment: @imulsion After half health, withers will completely deflect all arrows. Splash potions might work, but that's more work than it's worth.

Comment: Everything works except for the water placed to stop things breaking, as you can't place water in the nether - is there anyway that lava would stop explosions

Comment: Success. Using water so that it doesn't blow anything up i managed to do this using an obsidian ceiling, i wasn't expecting it to work but it does, now i just need to make it more efficient

Answer (score 0):

make an obsidian tube so that it goes down than close the roof push the floor up so that it starts to suffocate than dispense arrows (tipped or no),splash potions of harming and poison and than poor water on its head. Than use a hopper that leads into a minecart and a chest that leads to your base.